# switch asp.net listview to edit mode without reload all data

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can edit one row in listview without reload all data (i.e:reload all data in page 3)?
When i click on the edit link, every lable in each column convert to textbox (or dropdownlist or ...) without need to reload all data.
After that i click save link, and flush all change in database (with ajax).
In the other words, what is the low cost solution to edit one row in listview asp.net control?

Comment: But update panel reload all data in async manner

Comment: that seems to me the one **Low Cost Solution**